# Sliding door cannot open after fixing strike plate

Tags: doors, latches

The strike plate was loose (the door wouldn't latch properly), so I tightened the strike plate and closed the door. But now the door is stuck and I cannot open it. What should I do? Do I need to undo the screws (top and bottom) to remove the door handle?  I would greatly appreciate any advice on this!

The strike plate kind of looked like this: https://www.homedepot.ca/product/ideal-security-screen-door-latch-set-white-/1000743052

[image]

Comment: Try lifting the door from the handle and sliding it back, once open you'll have to adjust the strike plate position.

Comment: I agree with @matt. it appears the hook that goes into the strike has found a way to engage the strike. There should be some room at the top of the sliding panel to lift the door and the hook of of the strike. Maybe even moving the latch lever may do it. If the hook is part of the handle body that comes off by removing screws, and not into the edge of the door, that should work too.

Comment: Hook for the latch has probably engaged the strike and there isn't enough slack to make it come out, or the elevation is wrong.  You should be able to disassemble the handle and remove the latch.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely have to lift or lower the door via the adjustment screws or physically to get the door open.

Once open and readjusted so the door slides properly (if adjustment was needed to open the door), take note of the latch position and adjust the latch plate accordingly, either up or down.